How to integrate $\int\frac{\sqrt{x^{6}}+5x^{2}+3\sqrt{x^{2}}+7}{x^{3}+2x^{2}+5\sqrt{x^{2}}+6}dx$
How to integrate $$\int\frac{\sqrt{x^{6}}+5x^{2}+3\sqrt{x^{2}}+7}{x^{3}+2x^{2}+5\sqrt{x^{2}}+6}dx$$ ?
My way of Approach:
I considered:
$\sqrt{x^{6}}=x^{3}, \sqrt{x^{2}}=x$ for $x\geq 0$
The following integration will become:
$$\int\frac{x^{3}+5x^{2}+3x+7}{x^{3}+2x^{2}+5x+6}dx$$
$$=x+\int\frac{3x^{2}-2x+1}{x^{3}+2x^{2}+5x+6}dx +C$$
Now I am facing problem in integrating $$\int\frac{3x^{2}-2x+1}{x^{3}+2x^{2}+5x+6}dx$$
I know how to proceed:
$3x^{2}-2x+1=A\frac{d}{dx}(x^{3}+2x^{2}+5x+6)+B$
But after this step, I can't approach further.
Also I am confused whether my logic is correct or not. Please tell me.

Case 1 : $~x \geq 0.~$ Case 2: $~x < 0.$

This is Ok. But if I tell to $$\int\frac{\sqrt{x^{6}}+5x^{2}+3\sqrt{x^{2}}+7}{x^{3}+2x^{2}+5\sqrt{x^{2}}+6}dx$$ , then how to do that ? My main reason for asking this question is that in case of integration, how to integrate?

Ok. I will @user1556492

Please help me out

Ok. I will. But please help me @AnneBauval

You can follow the usual algorithm for integrating a rational function (partial fractions and such). But you won't necessarily enjoy it, because you need the roots of a cubic, and those aren't clean. Even Mathematica spits out just a generic sum over the set of roots (one real, two complex conjugates).

So the procedure is the same as for example here, but the root of the denominator won't be simple, so the numbers become hairy.

This question is similar to: Solving $\int{\frac{2x^{4}-5x^{3}+11x^{2}-2x-10}{x^{3}-3x^{2}+7x-5}dx}$. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please send me the link of Mathematica@JyrkiLahtonen

Where is that problem from? I find strange that a teacher or a textbook can propose an exercise whose solution is so horrible. Or maybe the exercise was not exactly this?

I will help you with the last integral, if you have further questions, please tell me. \begin{align}\int\frac{3x^2-2x+1}{x^3+2x^2+5x+6}dx&=\int \frac{-6x-4}{x^3+2x^2+5x+6}dx+\int\frac{1}{x^3+2x^2+5x+6}d(x^3+2x^2+5x+6)\\  \end{align}\begin{align}\int\frac{-6x-4}{x^3+2x^2+5x+6}dx&=-6\int \frac{(x+\frac{2}{3})}{(x+\frac{2}{3})^3+\frac{11}{3}(x+\frac{2}{3})+\frac{88}{27}}dx\end{align}
Let $t=x+\frac{2}{3}$ and the final integral is $$\int \frac{t}{t^3+\frac{11}{3}t+\frac{88}{27}}dt$$ which is equal to this.

The problem is much simpler is you call $(a,b,c)$ the roots of the cubic in $t$ and use partial fraction decomposition. The real root is $$-\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{11} \sinh
\left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{\sqrt{11}}\right)\right)$$ Just deflate to get a quartic term..

@ClaudeLeibovici Thank you. Yes, that's true. But it is also a little bit complicated when doing the decomposition. If OP wants this, I'll show some details.

WA reult is so awful !
